# How create full inheritance for objects (not only for prototypes)?

Tags: javascript

I want to read the own properties of the parent from the children.

The parent object:

```
var module = function() {
  this.group = new group('Male');
  this.thumb = new thumb('Loly');
}
```

The child objects:

```
var group = function( name ) {
  this.name = name || '';
}
var thumb = function( name ) {
  this.name = name || '';
}
```

I want to write a `function extend (child, parent ) {...}`, that after applying `extend( group, module )` we have
`module.group.thumb == module.thumb`  (i.e. we can access all parent own properties from `module.group`). So next log doesn't print **undefiend** after `group.select()`:

```
group.prototype.select = function( name ) {
      console.log( this.thumb);
}
```

Number of own properties of parent object may be uncertain, so simple linking is not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want classical inheritance against javascript prototypal inheritance. John resig little inheritance piece below might be useful as it allows the reference to parents methods (which could be modified to access properties too as only there type is different)

http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

Comment: Thanx. But it isn't solve my problem. Because if we dynamically add new property to module, we still can't see it from childs.